# how to set time in ajax slider control's maximam or minimum value properties? in asp.net

Tags: ajax, asp.net-ajax

i want to set property of ajax slider control's maximum or minimum properties??

in this two properties ...it take only integer value but i want to give date value to that properties..

ajex toolbar is very new to use..

help to get out this..

Comment: you need to post your code or describe what framework (if any) are you using etc. nobody will help you from these two sentences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to to set those properties to date values. If you want the user to be able to use the control to select a time interval, then you would need to set the control's Minimum, Maximum and Step properties appropriately.

eg

To allow the user to select an interval of up to an hour, in minutes, you might configure the slider as follows:

```
<ajaxToolkit:SliderExtender ID="SliderExtender1" runat="server"
TargetControlID="Slider1"
Minimum="0"
Maximum="60"
Steps="60" />
```